# Is there an official list of abbreviations for ballroom dances?

Tags: terminology, dancing

When looking around for notes on ballroom dancing you will stumble across many abbreviations, many of them are very clear. But the dances itself (referring to the usual ten ballroom dances in a competition) seem to lack clear abbreviations.

While searching I have found

- S/SA/SB for Samba, C/CC/CCC for Cha Cha Cha, R/RU/RB for Rumba, J/JI/JV for Jive, P/PA/PD for Paso Doble
- W/SW for Slow Waltz, VW/WW for Viennese Waltz, T/TA/TG for Tango, F/SF for Slow Foxtrot, Q/QS for Quickstep

Unfortunately, I have found no official reference (maybe from WDSF) which lists the abbreviations. Is there such a list or if not why not?

<sub>Please note that I have not found a tag for dancing here on Sports.SE, so if it is off-topic I would be glad if you could point me to some other place.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Seems I have found at least a regional answer. The German “Turnier- und Sportordnung des Deutschen Tanzsportverbandes e.V. (TSO)” (the reference for the DTV) lists the following abbreviations (according to the German names of the dances) on page 19 (version dated January 2019):

- Langsamer Walzer: LW
- Tango: TG
- Wiener Walzer: WW
- Slowfox: SF
- Quickstep: QU
- Samba: SB
- Cha-Cha-Cha: CC
- Rumba: RB
- Paso Doble: PD
- Jive: JV

Comment: I'm still waiting for a more international answer…

Comment: I don't think you're really going to find one (an internationally accept set), as each federation or organization uses it's own rules and abbreviations. For the US, for example, in the NDCA Rules and Application forms, they do not abbreviate. Yet, the USDC Application uses 17 different abbreviations, none of which are listed above.